# r.cost multiple destinations

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to calculate the optimal route from one archaeological site to multiple sites. I already have the r.cost raster. My question is if I can use r.drain to multiple destination points.

Comment: Doesn't "optimal route" imply to get a single result? Or do you want to visit all sites one after the other? Then it might be seen moreover as network problem, hence "travelling salesman" (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.salesman.html) on a vector graph.

Comment: not necessarily, if you look at the dialog box of r.drain it literally say "map coordinate of starting point(s) (E,N). Moreover if you look at the help it also says "The coordinate parameter consists of map E and N grid coordinates of a starting point. Each x,y pair is the easting and northing (respectively) of a starting point from which a least-cost corridor will be developed. The vector_points parameter can take multiple vector maps containing additional starting points. Up to 1024 starting points can be input from a combination of the coordinate and vector_points parameters."

Comment: Nevertheless I have not found how to put the coordinates of multiple points. What I want is an individual route from the "center" to each one of my sites and that the route calculated takes in to account movement impediments, like topography, for instance

Comment: By the way the tool you are porposing is for vector layers, I wonder if it can it take  in to account an anistropic surface.

Comment: What's wrong with 'start_points' parameter in GRASS 7 (vector_points in GRASS 6.4)?

Comment: I am using grass 6.4 under qgis, The dialog box has two place to put coordinates, so I wonder what is the format to input more than two "starting points". I have tried to separate them with semicolons or spaces and all I get is a raster with no routes in it. No even with converting the raster to a line. So the problem is how to declare more tha one starting point. The tool help does not calrify the matter also. I tried to follow  Netler and Mitasova (2008) Open source GIS: a Grass GIS approach and no luck also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GRASS GIS 6.4 r.drain [manual page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.drain.html) shows:

**coordinate**=x,y[,x,y,...]
Map coordinates of starting point(s) (E,N)

so just enter your coordinates as:

r.drain coordinate=x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 ...

or you can save the coordinates as a vector and use parameter **vector_points**. These parameters are renamed in GRASS 7, check the [manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.drain.html).

Comment: The way you describe works perfectly. I already check the manual, even quote it, but I did not notice anything specific about my question.