# Least cost path: single source point, multiple target points

Tags: qgis, cost-path, least-cost

I have a single source point in EPSG:3857, and a set of points, also in EPSG:3857. I calculated a slope layer from SRTM (in EPSG:3857) in the extent of the complete set of points. I would like to use this layer as a friction layer for calculating least cost path. I would like to do this in a way that one single action provides a set of paths, from the source point to the every destination point.

So far I tried using `Least Cost Path` and `r.cost` + `r.drain` and I'm able only to calculate one single path. (In the case of `r.drain` from closest destination point to the source point.) I am unable to produce a set of paths no matter what I try. I would welcome instructions on how I could calculate multiple cost paths, using slope layer only as cost. I am attaching the points used,for review: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar4Fhb0r6aPcrDPF4rlLZlin4262?e=adYYtP

Please note that I edited the friction surface (slope layer) and removed larger water bodies from the extent, in order not to interfere with the calculation.

UPDATE: Solution behind this link [r.cost multiple destinations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167287/r-cost-multiple-destinations) is a working one> however my previous attempts to use it failed. In this particular case i believe that CRS was the problem - I had changed CRS from the EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326, and the whole process started running as intended.

Comment: Check this out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167287/r-cost-multiple-destinations

Comment: I have edited the question, but can confirm that solution that you linked me to is a functional one: i had tried to use it beforehand, but the process kept being interrupted. More details in updated text of the question.